# Is there any way to calculate the true,false positives and negatives for a regression problem

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I am trying to predict the glucose values of the patients for example values like 45,256,115 etc. based on some features. Currently I am calculating the accuracy in means of RMSE,MSE,R². Is there any way to calculate the accuracy in means of a confusion matrix by setting a threshold value like ±10 for the value predicted. For example if the actual value is 110 and my prediction is 100 then we can tell that's it's kind of accurate since 100+10=110 where 10 is the threshold value. Any suggestions and some code to elaborate it will be very helpful.

Comment: What is it that you would like to do? Is it that you are not looking for a continuous outcome but rather something like "glucose is over a threshold", or is it that you would like a more in-depth view of the individual predictions and actuals?

Comment: Yeah first I focused on continuous outcome but now I want to test how accurate the value can be predicted along with the threshold value without using regression scoring metrics.

Comment: How about reframing it in a classification problem?

Comment: I don't think it can be reframed since I need to predict the blood glucose value.. any suggestion to reframe it ?

Comment: How about? **glucose_value > THRESHOLD ? 1 : 0** Or *binning* it if you need more more resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there's no actual function in sklearn library that does that. However, that concept is relatively easy to implement: you can loop and compare each y_prediction with the respective y_true_value and increment TN, TP, FN, and FP accordingly to a certain threshold. For example:

`if abs(y_pred[i] - y_true[i]) <= threshold: 
     TP += 1
 elif abs(y_pred[i] - y_true[i]) > threshold:
     TN += 1
 ...`

Don't forget to reverse transform the scaling on y_true and y_pred values first.

Comment: Yeah thanks that helps. By the way do you know a way of calculating the opimum threshold value?

Comment: you're welcome! I think it depends on the nature of the problem, and tbh you might be in better position than me to know what threshold makes sense or could be optimal.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense but is there any formula to calculate the threshold value?